# How can I make a parametrized Job?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to send parameters to my reader.

```
public JpaPagingItemReader<Person> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['PersonId']}")
String id){
    JpaPagingItemReader<Person> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<Person>();
    reader.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    reader.setQueryString("SELECT p from "+Person.class.getName()+" p where Id = "+id);
    reader.setPageSize(10);
    return reader;
}
```

This in turn would want the parameter to come from step and job methods.

```
@Bean
public Step step(String id){
    return stepBuilder.get("step").<Person,Person>chunk(100).reader(reader(id))
        .processor(processor())
        .writer(writer()).build();
}

@Bean
public Job personJob(String id){
    return jobBuilder.get("personJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step(id)).end().build(); 
}
```

My main method implements `CommandLineRunner` and the run method is overridden as follows -

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    JobParameters parameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
        .addString("PersonId", "1")
        .toJobParameters();
    jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);
}
```

The method above will not accept `jobParameters` as `jobLauncher.run(job,parameters)` expects `job` to have no arguments but it does not accept `jobLauncher.run(job(id),parameters)`.

The error received as -

```
Parameter 0 of method personJob in com.example.JobConfig required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
```

Is there any way to get `id` in my reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reader should be step-scoped to able to inject job parameters:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JpaPagingItemReader<Person> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['PersonId']}") String id){
   JpaPagingItemReader<Person> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<Person>();
   reader.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
   reader.setQueryString("SELECT p from "+Person.class.getName()+" p where Id = "+id);
   reader.setPageSize(10);
   return reader;
}
```

This is explained in the [StepScope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#step-scope) section of the reference documentation.

You don't need to propagate the id in the signature of the step and job beans methods, you can pass `null` as follows:

```
@Bean
public Step step() {
   return stepBuilder.get("step")
    .<Person,Person>chunk(100)
    .reader(reader(null))
    .processor(processor())
    .writer(writer())
    .build();
}

@Bean
public Job personJob(){
    return jobBuilder.get("personJob")
       .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
       .flow(step())
       .end()
       .build(); 
}
```

Finally, your `run` method is correct, there is nothing to change there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You get this exception because `public Step step(String id)` is equivalent to `public Step step(@Autowired String id)` and you don't have a String bean defined in context.

To pass the id from `JobParameters` object you need to declare `JobParameters jobParameters` bean and either use `@Value("#{jobParameters['PersonId']}"` or directly the `jobParameters` bean.

I'm not familiar with `Spring Batch` but I guess config should be similar to smth like this:

```
@Configuration
public class PersonJobConfig {

    @Bean
    public JobParameters jobParameters() {
        return new JobParametersBuilder().addString("PersonId", "1").toJobParameters();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(JobParameters jobParameters){
        return stepBuilder.get("step").<Person,Person>chunk(100).reader(reader(jobParameters.getString("PersonId"))
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job personJob(JobParameters jobParameters){
        return jobBuilder.get("personJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step(jobParameters.getString("PersonId"))).end().build(); 
    }

}
```